# Extracting single file from zip archive using Haskell

Tags: haskell, zip, zip-conduit

Using the [`zip-conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/zip-conduit) library, I want to extract a single file (e.g. `bar/foo.txt`) from the ZIP archive.

The example on hackage only shows how to extract all files at once. How can I extract only a single file or a list of files?

**Note:** This question was answered using Q&A-style and therefore intentionally doesn't show any research effort!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official example applies `extractFiles` to the `[FilePath]` as returned by `fileNames`. You can simply apply it to a custom list of filenames:

```
import Codec.Archive.Zip (withArchive, extractFiles)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main = do
    -- ZIP file name: First commandline arg
    zipPath:_ <- getArgs
    withArchive zipPath $
        extractFiles ["bar/foo.txt"] "."
```

This code will create a folder `bar` in the current working directory and extract the file `foo.txt` into said folder. If any such file already exists, it will be overwritten.

If you intend to extract to a custom filename (e.g. you want to extract `foo.txt` to your current working directory, not to the `bar` folder), you need to use conduits as shown in this example:

```
import Codec.Archive.Zip (withArchive, sourceEntry)
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB

main = do
    -- ZIP file name: First commandline arg
    zipPath:_ <- getArgs
    withArchive zipPath $
        sourceEntry "bar/foo.txt" $ CB.sinkFile "foo.txt"
```

Instead of using `CB.sinkFile` you can use any other [conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) sink.